# Zend instance in a subfolder of another Zend

Tags: zend-framework

Hi i have a Zend installation in main domain. 
Now i want to make a subfolder and run Zend for some testing purposes. I have copied all files from main site to subfolder named www2. But when i call the subfolder like `domain.com/www2` i think the main Zend instance get invoked and produces a `Message: Invalid controller specified (www2)` error?

my .htaccess of main Zend is

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/www2/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```

and Subfolder is like

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

What i am doing Wrong. I have full access to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in subfolder Zend in file application/Bootstrap.php add LIKE this:

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{
        $this->bootstrap('frontcontroller');
        /**
         * @var Zend_Controller_Front $front
         */
        $front = $this->getResource('frontcontroller');
        /**
         * @var Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite $router
         */
        $router = $front->getRouter();
        $router->addRoute('www2',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                'www2/:controller/:action',
                array('controller' => 'index',
                      'action' => 'index'))
        );
}
```

But may be you need another route...

UPD1:
first .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/www2*
RewriteRule ^.*$ www2/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i am new to zend can you please explain more. I mean how/where to add this ?

Comment: Tried but there is no luck. I doubt when i call subfolder the main Zend get invoked and it throws Controller not found error. Any other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a subdomain `www2.domain.com` pointing the `www2/public` directory and restore all `.htaccess` files to their normal single-site state.

This way, the www2 copy is completely standalone app with the same url and file structure as the original www site.

Comment: but i dont have access to domain to make nameserver pointing.

Comment: Aaah, I mis-interpreted your claim of full access to the server. Sorry. ;-)